# Assigning A Rating Using Radio Boxes and PHP

Tags: php, radio-button

I am making a website where people can rate the content with radio boxes numbered from 1-10. The radio box when selected sends the rating to the database and that works fine. I want then to perform an averaging calculation to find the average rating and output that result. I have tried a lot of ways but to no avail including using arrays. The term 'totalraters' is the total amount of people who have submitted a rating and the term 'ratingsum' is the total of all the radio box values ever submitted. I would be most grateful for any help.

```
<?php

$con2=mysqli_connect("myhost","user","password","place");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con2))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();


}
$value=$_POST['rating'];
$id=$_POST['id'];


mysqli_query  ($con2, "UPDATE table SET totalraters = totalraters + 1 WHERE id='$id'  ");
mysqli_query  ($con2, "UPDATE table SET ratingsum = ratingsum + '$value' WHERE id='$id' ");


//Works great up to here 



 $ratingsum = mysqli_query($con2, "SELECT ratingsum FROM table WHERE id='$id' ");
 $totalraters = mysqli_query($con2, "SELECT totalraters FROM table WHERE id='$id' ");




  IF ($totalraters != 0)  {
 $rating = (int)($ratingsum/$totalraters);

  }

mysqli_query ($con2, "UPDATE table SET rating ='$rating' WHERE id='$id'  ") or   trigger_error(mysqli_error($con2)); 



 mysqli_close($con2);

 header('Location: back to same page ');

 ?>
```

At the moment this returns me to the original page after the rating has been made but the current rating is always 1 instead of the correct result although it outputs the correct number of raters.

Answer (score 0):

Yippee I finally fixed it and your help was good too hichris123....many thanks!! This took me hours so I post that it may aid someone else.

```
<?php

$con2=mysqli_connect("webhost.com","account","password","user");

 // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con2))
  {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();


  }
  $value=$_POST['rating'];
 $id=$_POST['id'];


  mysqli_query  ($con2, "UPDATE table SET totalraters = totalraters + 1 WHERE      id='$id' ");
  mysqli_query  ($con2, "UPDATE table SET ratingsum = ratingsum + '$value' WHERE id='$id' ");


$query1 = mysqli_query($con2, "SELECT ratingsum FROM table WHERE id='$id' ");
$query2 = mysqli_query($con2, "SELECT totalraters FROM table WHERE id='$id' ");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
$ratingsum = intval($row['ratingsum']);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
$totalraters = intval($row2['totalraters']);


$rating = (intval($ratingsum/$totalraters));


mysqli_query ($con2, "UPDATE table SET rating = '$rating' WHERE id='$id' ");


 include ('index/starting page.html');
```